# How to compare all columns with one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

For the following df

```
                A       B       ..... THRESHOLD             
DATE                                       
2011-01-01       NaN       NaN  .....      NaN   
2012-01-01 -0.041158 -0.161571  ..... 0.329038   
2013-01-01  0.238156  0.525878  ..... 0.110370   
2014-01-01  0.606738  0.854177  ..... -0.095147   
2015-01-01  0.200166  0.385453  ..... 0.166235
```

I have to compare N number of columns like A,B,C .... with THRESHOLD and output the result like

```
df['A_CALC'] = np.where(df['A'] > df['THRESHOLD'], 1, -1)
df['B_CALC'] = np.where(df['B'] > df['THRESHOLD'], 1, -1)
```

How to apply the above for all columns (A,B,C ... ) without explicitly writing one statement per column ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `df.apply`:

```
In [670]: df.iloc[:, :-1]\
            .apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.THRESHOLD, 1, -1), axis=0)\
            .add_suffix('_CALC')
Out[670]: 
            A_CALC  B_CALC
Date                      
2011-01-01      -1      -1
2012-01-01      -1      -1
2013-01-01       1       1
2014-01-01       1       1
2015-01-01       1       1
```

If `THRESHOLD` is *not* your last column, you'd be better off using

```
df[df.columns.difference(['THRESHOLD'])].apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.THRESHOLD, 1, -1), axis=0).add_suffix('_CALC')
```

Comment: I think you could just using `where` function in `pandas`, rather than from `numpy`, still a nice solution

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe you can try this , by using `subtract`, should be faster than `apply`

```
(df.drop(['THRESHOLD'],axis=1).subtract(df.THRESHOLD,axis=0)>0)\
    .astype(int).replace({0:-1}).add_suffix('_CALC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following suffice?

```
for col in df.columns.values:
    if col!= 'THRESHOLD':
        newname = col+'_CALC'
        df[newname] = np.where(df[col] > df['THRESHOLD'], 1, -1)
```

Comment: Using a for loop when operating on pandas columns is never recommended.

Comment: Ouch! Why is that? I have never had an issue with it, although I can imagine it is quite time-consuming...

Comment: Exactly because it is time consuming :]

Comment: When you due with large scale , you will find those for loop kill the runing time , make the possible impossible

Answer (score 0):

I needed to compare **some** columns to one column **(changing some columns and keeping some columns unchanged)**. I used cs95's answer above and set an index.

- The columns that you want to keep go in the index (assume col1 and col2).
- If any column not in the index is greater than col2 then it gets a 1, otherwise 0.

**data:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(10,15), 'col2':range(1,6), 'col3':np.random.randn(5)+3,'col4':np.random.randn(5)+3,'col5':np.random.randn(5)})

    col1    col2    col3        col4        col5
0   10      1       2.741873    2.402274    -1.208714
1   11      2       3.328949    2.692367    -0.813730
2   12      3       5.074692    3.155199    -0.721969
3   13      4       2.725135    3.393867    -2.452344
4   14      5       3.626220    3.002514    -0.897204
```

**code:**

```
import numpy as np

df['col2_copy'] = df['col2']
df=df.set_index(['col1','col2'])
df=df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df['col2_copy'], 1, 0), axis=0).reset_index().drop(['col2_copy'],axis = 1)
```

**output:**

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   10      1       1       1       0
1   11      2       1       1       0
2   12      3       1       1       0
3   13      4       0       0       0
4   14      5       0       0       0
```